# exe file created by pyinstaller: scipy 'list' object has no attribute 'join' problem

Tags: python, scipy, pyqt, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I had a problem. I created an app with PyQt5, numpy, scipy, redis, etc. There is no problem run with python console. It works. But when I use the pyinstaller to make an exe file and run it, I have many errors.

First I had;

```
(haydars_env) C:\Users\haydarc\analysis_result>dist\app.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 18, in <module>
    from scipy import stats
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\haydarc\.conda\envs\haydars_env\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\scipy\__init__.py", line 136, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\haydarc\.conda\envs\haydars_env\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\scipy\_distributor_init.py", line 61, in <module>
  File "site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyiboot01_bootstrap.py", line 170, in __init__
  File "site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyiboot01_bootstrap.py", line 133, in _frozen_name
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'join'
[7028] Failed to execute script app
```

Second I had;

I read from google, someone said it may be numpy issue. So I uninstalled and reinstalled, there is no difference. I installed numpy+mkl, I had dll errors.

I also tried to use fbs, again there is no difference.

Can someone help me?

Note: Here is my libraries;

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QPlainTextEdit

# from pandasmodel import PandasModel
# Other libraries
import sys as  os
import sys
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import pickle
import redis
import zlib
import pandas
from pandasmodel import PandasModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox
from gui import Ui_MainWindow
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is coming from `import sys as os`. `os` is another frequently used module and many libraries are using it. The error you have is from `os.path.join` : instead of calling the `join` method of `os.path` module the scipy init is trying to access attribute `join` of `sys.path` attribute. just rename `sys` to a non popular name.

Comment: Thank you. By the way why are your renaming sys ?

Comment: To be honest, it was just a mistake. You saved my days, thank you again..